# Pytnon не пишет кириллицей из R Notebook

Tags: python, кириллица

Стоит Rstudio. Создаём чанк на Python. Но при попытке Python вывести кириллицу выдаёт ошибку.

```
print("привет")

Python 3.8.11 (D:/programs/anaconda3/python.exe)
Reticulate 1.20 REPL -- A Python interpreter in R.
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-4: truncated \uXXXX escape (<string>, line 1)
```

Если добвлю "r":

```
print(r"привет")

\u43f\u440\u438\u432\u435\u442
```

Это был бы UTF-8 в последней строчке, если бы \u043f\u0440\u0438\u0432\u0435\u0442. Но нули отсутствуют.

Как заставить Python печатать кириллицу?

In English: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69176044/python-in-r-notebook-doesnt-print-cyrillic

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант:

```
print(r"привет".replace("u", "u0").encode().decode('unicode_escape'))
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]